# how to replace string which has consecutive words without space in java

Tags: java

I have a file which has few consecutive words are repeated without space like below input.And my expected output should be like below.

```
String input = "These are appleapple and guavaguava"; 
and expected output is: These are apple and guava.
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a modification of this should work

```
String input = "These are appleapple and guavaguava"; 
String words [] = input.split(" ");

for (String w : words) {

    if (w.length() % 2 == 0) {
        String firstHalf = w.substring(0, w.length() / 2 );
        String secondHalf = w.substring(w.length() / 2);
        if (firstHalf.equals(secondHalf)) {
            System.out.println(firstHalf);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(w);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(w);
    }
}
```

As suggested by @zlakad, it could be improved by

```
String input = "These are appleapple and guavaguava";
String[] words = input.split(" ");

for (String w : words) {
    int half = w.length() / 2;
    String firstHalf = w.substring(0, half);  // split in half
    String secondHalf = w.substring(half);
    if (firstHalf.equals(secondHalf)) {  // if equal halves then only print one
        System.out.print(firstHalf + " ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(w + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: @tim Thanks for the edit, especially `String[] words`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using backreferences:

```
String input = "These are appleapple and guavaguava"; 
input = input.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)\\1\\b", "$1");
System.out.println(input);

These are apple and guava
```

### Demo

The backreference works by matching `\b(\w+)(\1)\b`.  The `\w+` term will greedily take the longest word possible, and a match will only occur if the remainder of the word matches `\1`, which is the portion we just matched up to that point.  The word boundaries are necessary to avoid the edge case pointed out by @Wombat e.g. `appleapples`, where without boundaries we would falsely detect a repeat word.

There is a caveat here that this approach would not work if, for example, there were three strings repeated together.

Comment: try `String input = "These are appleapples and guavaguava"; `

Comment: @ScaryWombat Adding anchors on both sides of the replacement pattern seemed to fix it...at least your edge case.  If you have other problems, let me know.

Comment: Tim, I won't even pretend to understand how that works ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat It's way easier than you think.  Let me add some info to the answer, maybe you will see another flaw :-)

Comment: It works for me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @seshadrip Is there a problem with my answer?

Comment: hmm, I thought this answer was accepted

Comment: Your comment makes no sense.  Can you provide an input where my answer fails?

Comment: @Tim,I am getting exact result what i am expecting .Thank for your reply.

Comment: try this String input="These are appleappleapple and guavaguava" which is failing.

Comment: I gave a caviat that my answer does not cover triply repeated words.  Nor did your original question mention that.  You might want to open a new question.